# Why am I receiving CS1061 error in FluentValidation MustAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net, fluentvalidation, .net-6.0

I'm trying to create some validation rules using static extension methods for `IRuleBuilderOptions` so I don't have to keep repeating myself when creating validators for Creating and Updating my objects.

For some reason I keep getting CS1061 errors for the `country.Id` in the `MustAsync` unique checks. I have tried replacing arrow functions with brackets and `return`, tried `async`/`await`. They all result in the same error. Intellisense shows that `country` is of type `Country`, and `Id` is a public property with both public getter and setter, so I'm not sure what I'm missing? I tried compiling in case it was just an Intellisense issue, but compilation fails with the same error.

Note: Using VS2022 / .Net6

```
public class Country
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Code2 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Code3 { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; } = 1000;
    public bool Enabled { get; set; } = true;
}

public class CountryCreateValidator : AbstractValidator<Country>
{
    public CountryCreateValidator(IApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Name(dbContext);
        RuleFor(x => x.Code2).Code2(dbContext);
        RuleFor(x => x.Code3).Code3(dbContext);
    }
}

public class CountryUpdateValidator : AbstractValidator<Country>
{
    public CountryUpdateValidator(IApplicationDbContext dbContext)
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Id).NotEmpty();
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).Name(dbContext);
        RuleFor(x => x.Code2).Code2(dbContext);
        RuleFor(x => x.Code3).Code3(dbContext);
    }
}

public static class CountryRules
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Name<Country>(this IRuleBuilder<Country, string> ruleBuilder, IApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
        ruleBuilder.NotNull().NotEmpty().MaximumLength(64)
            .MustAsync((country, name, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                return dbContext.Countries.AllAsync(x => x.Id == country.Id /* error here */ || x.Name != name, cancellationToken);
            }).WithMessage(FvConstants.UNIQUE);

    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Code2<Country>(this IRuleBuilder<Country, string> ruleBuilder, IApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
        ruleBuilder.NotEmpty().Length(2).Matches("^[A-Z]{2}$").WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be two uppercase letters")
            .MustAsync((country, code2, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                return dbContext.Countries.AllAsync(x => x.Id == country.Id || x.Code2 != code2, cancellationToken);
            }).WithMessage(FvConstants.UNIQUE);

    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Code3<Country>(this IRuleBuilder<Country, string> ruleBuilder, IApplicationDbContext dbContext) =>
        ruleBuilder.NotEmpty().Length(3).Matches("^[A-Z]{3}$").WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be three uppercase letters")
            .MustAsync((country, code3, cancellationToken) =>
            {
                return dbContext.Countries.AllAsync(x => x.Id == country.Id || x.Code3 != code3, cancellationToken);
            }).WithMessage(FvConstants.UNIQUE);
}

public class FvConstants
{
    public const string UNIQUE = "{PropertyName} must be unique";
}
```

Here is a screenshot showing proper typeing of the `country` parameter and the error I am getting...

[image: Proper parameter type, but error when accessing property]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Country` is the name of generic parameter of your methods, not a type name. Just remove `<Country>` from the signatures:

```
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Name(...
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Code2(...
public static IRuleBuilderOptions<Country, string> Code3(...
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't believe I missed that. Was looking at the FluentValidation documentation and their example `IRuleBuilderOptions` extension methods were for generic types. I replaced all of the `T`s with `Country` and completely spaced on removing the generic parameter.